# Can someone explain to me why I am only able to type in one letter in the text input?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

For some reason when I try to do this event, it allows for only one letter in the text input.  I tried searching for an answer and couldn't figure it out, can someone help me?

```
let button = document.getElementById("button");
let input = document.getElementById("userInput");
let ul = document.getElementById("list");

input.addEventListener("keypress", function(e){
    
    if(e.keyCode == 13){
        let li = document.createElement("li");
        li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value))
    ul.appendChild(li)}
    
    input.value = "";
} 

);
```

There is another event, but this one works perfectly when alone and there is no text limit

```
button.addEventListener("click", function(){
    let li = document.createElement("li");
    if(input.value.length > 0){
        li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value))
    ul.appendChild(li)}
    
    input.value = "";
} 

);
```

Comment: because you're using `input.value = "";`?

Comment: but thats at the end

Comment: Yes but it happens everytime in the end of your keypress or click event so you wont' be able to write more...

Comment: Wow.  But it's set to only do it after I click key code 13 wich is enter

Comment: I just realized I'm an absolute bafoon.  Super rookie mistake, I thought it was inside the if statement.  I'm sorry for wasting your guyses time.

Answer (score 1):

It happens because everytime you press a key it is setting the `input.value` to be empty. You may want to move the closing bracket to be after the `input.value = "";`. Like so:

```js
let button = document.getElementById("button");
let input = document.getElementById("userInput");
let ul = document.getElementById("list");

input.addEventListener("keypress", function(e){
    
    if(e.keyCode == 13){
        let li = document.createElement("li");
        li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value))
        ul.appendChild(li)
    
        input.value = "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Then how can I reset the input to have zero characters without the problem happening?

Comment: I don't understand the question. "how can I clear the input without resulting in the input cleared" doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

As others have alluded to, `input.value = "";` was emptying your input on each `keypress` event and you needed to move it inside of your if condition.

It seems like you realized the issue but here is a working snippet using your code:

```js
let button = document.getElementById("button");
let input = document.getElementById("userInput");
let ul = document.getElementById("list");

input.addEventListener("keypress", function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      let li = document.createElement("li");
      li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value))
      ul.appendChild(li)
      input.value = "";
    }
  }

);

button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    let li = document.createElement("li");
    if (input.value.length > 0) {
      li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value))
      ul.appendChild(li)
    }

    input.value = "";
  }

);
```

```html
<button id="button">button</button><input id="userInput"></input><br/>
<ul id="list"></ul>
```